# Bibtex is not working in windows

Tags: bibtex, miktex

my example code is not working with Windows and MiKTeX. I don't know why.
I try to compile my bibliography with `bibtex`:

```
@UNPUBLISHED{bibtex.a,
author = "Oren Patashnik",
title = "{{\BibTeX}ing}",
note = "Documentation for general {\BibTeX} users",
month = "8$^{th}$~" # feb,
language = "USenglish",
year = 1988, }
```

This is the `tex` Code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{cite}
\begin{document}

Test\cite{bibtex.a}.
\bibliography{verzeichnis1}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\end{document
```

I am doing the `latex` - `bibtex` - `Latex` - `Latex` commands on both Systems.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What is your error message? Maybe missing definition of `\BibTeX`?

Comment: There's a missing closing brace in `\end{document`

Answer (score 1):

Well, added the missing `}` in your code I can compile your code with one error.  This error shows that command `\BibTeX` is not defined in your code or you do not call a package defining it.

So I added the code

```
\newcommand{\BibTeX}{Bib\TeX}
```

to define `\BibTeX`.

The following Code compiles without error and only one warning (okay, package `filecontents` is only used here to have bib file and TeX code in one MWE):

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@UNPUBLISHED{bibtex.a,
  author = "Oren Patashnik",
  title = "{{\BibTeX}ing}",
  note = "Documentation for general {\BibTeX} users",
  month = "8$^{th}$~" # feb,
  language = "USenglish",
  year = 1988, 
}
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{cite}
\newcommand{\BibTeX}{Bib\TeX} % <=======================================

\begin{document}

Test\cite{bibtex.a}.

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document} % <======================================================
```

results in the following pdf:

[image: resulting pdf]

I'm using current MikTeX 2.9 on Windows.